# Memory layout of globals

Tags: c++, memory-layout

Consider

```
Foo data[]={{...},{...},{...}};
Foo data_end={...};
```

If the end marker is defined right after the array, is it guaranteed that

```
&data[3]==&data_end
```

I do not want having to count the number of elements in data manually.

It happens to look OK in gdb without any optimization option, but before using it I need to know that the compiler cannot move `data_end`. If it can, how can I do instead.

Comment: just divide the size by the number of elements or add a constant and put it in the []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not a reliable assumption that the compiler places the variables in any order or any alignment. There can be gaps between the variables for alignment and I've already seen compilers that order variables alphabetically.

If you want to know the pointer to the element that is *not* in the array you need to know the number of array elements.

```
#define _dimof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
Foo data[] = ... ;
// The type of the variable has been changed.
Foo* data_end = &data[_dimof(data)];
```

You may remove this paragraph since it has been added in order to fix a syntax error in the code.

Comment: In this case, this will take less space, since `sizeof(Foo)==3*sizeof(void*)`

Comment: @user877329 This depends on the definition of Foo what was not shown in the question. More notable you drop the dummy variable whoms address is all you want.

Answer (score 4):

Not only what you request is not guaranteed, but moreover, a C++03-compliant implementation *must* ensure that `&data[3] != &data_end`:

> 5.10 Equality operators[expr.eq]
>
> 1 … Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same object or function, or both point one past the end of the same array.

In C++11, it is a little more complicated:

> Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (3.9.2).

3.9.2 notes:

> … If an object of type `T` is located at an address `A`, a pointer of type *cv* `T*` whose value is the address `A` is said to point to that object, regardless of how the value was obtained. [Note: for instance, the address one past the end of an array (5.7) would be considered to point to an unrelated object of the array’s element type that might be located at that address. … —end note]

Thus, the new standard allows that a complying implementation *might* yield true in your comparison; still, there are no guarantees.

If you need to count the number of elements of an array, use the following stock macro:

```
#define countof(ARR) (sizeof (ARR) / sizeof *(ARR))
```

Or if you don't like macros, use the following function:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t countof(T (&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

The latter option, however, needs that your compiler support the `constexpr` keyword to be full functional equivalent of the former.

Comment: I downvoted you because you presented the macro like it was a viable option.

Comment: @Puppy, Actually macro *is* a viable option. There may be two reasons for that: 1. Some of us still have to cope with compilers which are not fully C++11-compliant and do not support the `constexpr` keyword. Without the `constexpr` you cannot do the following: `int a[] = { … }; int b[countof(a)];` 2. Some of us write header files which are intended to be included from both C and C++ compilation units. In such cases, as you might notice, templates cannot be used at all.

Comment: The OP has no such requirement. Also, if he would define his array as `boost::array`, there is no problem in the first place, as you can simply request the size directly. He mentions no requirement for the result to be a constant expression. In short, you're posting crappy code for requirements that do not apply here.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy So a complient compiler must add padding between the last element and next global object, or put it completely somewhere else. Note that we are in the same translation unit. But harper said they may sort things alphabetically.

Comment: @user877329, There is no obligation on the implementation to act in any prescribed manner. Note that generally, layout is defined by *both* compiler and linker: objects defined in different compilation units *may* get intermixed (if you use the `-fdata-sections` option or its equivalent). Of course, from the practical point of view, nobody will write a linker which does that just for fun; there must be a reason. For example, incremental linking may cause data and code from different compilation units to become intermixed.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy The point is that these addresses should be allowed to be the same, since I am referring to to the element right after the array and if the compiler did place the dummy directly afterwards "both point one past the end of the same array". By definition of the address operator, the standard cannot require these objects to have different locations. If it did, there would be a contradiction that there is no obligation on the memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not reliable, in C++11, just do

```
for (/* const */ Foo& foo : data) {
    // stuff with foo.
}
```